# How can I incorporate a looping background image into my game that does NOT cover the obstacles?

Tags: javascript, background-image

I am a beginner at javascript, starting about 5 weeks ago, and our teacher would like us to edit an existing code [from this website](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trygame_default_gravity)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
<script>

var myGamePiece;
var myObstacles = [];
var myScore;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
    myGamePiece.gravity = 0.05;
    myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.score = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "text") {
            ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
        this.hitBottom();
    }
    this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;
            this.gravitySpeed = 0;
        }
    }
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            return;
        } 
    }
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
        x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
        minHeight = 20;
        maxHeight = 200;
        height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
        minGap = 50;
        maxGap = 200;
        gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
        myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
        myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        myObstacles[i].x += -1;
        myObstacles[i].update();
    }
    myScore.text="SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
    myScore.update();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}

function accelerate(n) {
    myGamePiece.gravity = n;
}
</script>
<br>
<button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)" onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)">ACCELERATE</button>
<p>Use the ACCELERATE button to stay in the air</p>
<p>How long can you stay alive?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and I have done the [following so far](https://pastebin.com/r3JyKUX1).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:5px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #87CEEB;
}
img {
    display: none;
    z-index: -1;

}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/GwrpU8z.png">
<script>

var myGamePiece;
var myObstacles = [];
var myScore;
var myBackground;

var airballoon = document.querySelector("img");

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(80, 80, "red", 10, 120, "image");
    myGamePiece.gravity = 0.05;
    myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
    myBackground = new component(656, 270, "https://i.imgur.com/qqbnFe8.jpg", 0, 0, "background");
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 780;
        this.canvas.height = 400;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    if (type == "image" || type == "background") {
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.src = color;
    }    
    this.score = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "text") {
            ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        } else if (this.type == "image" || type == "background") {
            ctx.drawImage(airballoon, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            if (type == "background") {
                ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x + this.width, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            }
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
        if (this.type == "background") {
            if (this.x == -(this.width)) {
                this.x = 0;
        this.hitBottom();
    }
    this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;
            this.gravitySpeed = 0;
        }
    }
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            return;
        } 
    }
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(200)) {
        x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
        minHeight = 120;
        maxHeight = 210;
        height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
        minGap = 120;
        maxGap = 210;
        gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
        myObstacles.push(new component(50, height, "white", x, 0));
        myObstacles.push(new component(50, x - height - gap, "white", x, height + gap));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        myObstacles[i].x += -1;
        myObstacles[i].update();
    }
    myScore.text="SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
    myScore.update();
    myBackground.newPos();
    myBackground.update();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}

function accelerate(n) {
    myGamePiece.gravity = n;
}
</script>
<br>
<button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)" onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)">ACCELERATE</button>
<p>Use the ACCELERATE button to stay in the air</p>
<p>How long can you stay alive?</p>
</body>
</html>

== This program was made by **** with source code by www.w3schools.com ==
```

I am currently struggling to add a looping background to my game. When I attempted to follow what this site used to create a looping background, all that happened was the hot air balloon appearing twice (one as the component and one as the background, but it covers the obstacles!)
Can someone please help me figure this out? Thank you! (Also yes I am well aware that the code we're using is apparently not good, as I've been advised by other coders, but my teacher is insistent on us using it)

Comment: Welcome to [so]! That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code until you have a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem? This will increase your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a `z-index` value to the style for your background image?

```
img {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

This may help.

Comment: I edited my code to include more of this code https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trygame_image_background_loop
and to put in your suggestion but it still doesn't work!